# Data entry like destination field mail app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I need implement a Data entry like receiver field in mail app (Ex. To: pinco@gmail.com).
In particular in mail app each receiver is added and circle in blue color. This is my objective.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, here's a great library written by a friend that does exactly what you want:

[**Multi Recipient Picker Control**](http://www.softwareops.com/blogs/iPhone/iPhoneDevBlog_files/de891167adf425b139ddc1c27564b83b-44.html)

Comment: Great library! I try to use this library but I have a question: I need to match the element with my custom array not with address. It is possible? Can you help me to customized this library?

Comment: I can't tell you how to change everything, I'm not familiar with the library, but after a quick look it appears that the primary place you'll change things is in `MultiRecipientModel.h` and `MultiRecipientModel.m`, where the matching addresses and address details are returned to the viewController.

Comment: The URL of the code doesn't work anymore. Do you have a mirror link ?